# simple code editor with snippets panel?

Tags: html, code-snippets

I use Webstorm as my IDE and Brackets for some quicker stuff.

Is there a light weight editor similar to brackets that has a snippets panel like Dreamweaver? or maybe one that has a plug in or extension that adds a snippets panel?

I'm familiar with live templates in Webstorm but I don't believe there is a way to have a list of them in a panel that is always visible. I much prefer to have a big panel of commonly used blocks of code and html tags that are always visible that I can just click on.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Only:

Notepad++ has a a snippet plug in which does the same thing. After installing Notepad++ you simply click  the Plugin menu -> Plugin Manager. The tick snippets and press install. The rest is done for you.

Alternatives:
Sublime Text has a snippet tool but it's not the same as as Dreamweavers snippet panel.

Comment: Awesome. I'll check it out as soon as I get home. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks again, but After checking it out I think I'm going to just stick it out with Dreamweaver for when I need this feature.